# Is there a way to keep Game Center signed in on the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, settings, game-center

I've been making a lot of light changes to my code, and I only own one apple device. To test out Game Center, I've been pairing my device with the iOS simulator. It is highly irritating, because every slight modification of code results in me having to sign back into Game Center and enter my password on the simulator. My iPhone, however, saved my Game Center account info and remembers it every time I launch the app. Is there a way to have my simulator behave as my iPhone? (Is there a way to make my simulator remember an apple id for Game Center so that I don't have to enter my password every time?)

Answer (score 4):

Just like on the regular iPhone if you go to Settings > Game Center and log into your account, every time you run the simulator it will log in automatically for you. You have to do this for each of the devices (3.5 inch, 4 inch, iPad, etc). The simulator remembers information like it is a regular device (high scores, etc.). Hope this helps!